# Get an object inside of an object's location

Tags: javascript

So I have a program that has objects inside of objects. I need to access the objects attributes later, and I'm giving elements an attribute called location to hold this. I have a massive object that looks something like this

```
var story = Object()
story.s1 = {
    lore:"Stuff",
    choices:[
    {name:"Stuff",link:{lore:"Aye",choices:[]}},
    {name:"Stuff",link:{lore:"Aye",choices:[]}},
    {name:"Stuff",link:{lore:"Aye",choices:[]}}
    ]
}
```

Now what I have is a loop that gets each attribute and checks if it has individual attributes and the final code comes out to being something like this

```
story.s1.choices[1].link.lore
```

This is a location I want to put as an attribute (data-location, or location) into an HTML element as a string so the location can be edited later. Naturally, it just runs the code and gives me "Aye" back, and I cannot turn the code into a string. Any ideas how to turn this into a string?

So, what I'm trying to achieve is converting code into an unparsed string. For example, assuming that i is 0, I'd want to make

```
story.s1.choices[i].link.lore
```

into

```
"story.s1.choices[0].link.lore"
```

Also, a large complication of this is that I have a loop that runs complex code like this:

```
story.eval("s"+i).choices[i].link.choices[i].link.choices[i]... etc.
```

And why do I need all of this? I'm going to make input elements like this

```
<input location = "Put location string here" oninput = "parse(this.location)"/>
```

through JavaScript to make an editor for changing values within an object, which is a project I'm developing to assist myself with the creation of branching stories.

Comment: What you've posted isn't valid javascript. `obj.attributes` is an array but you're attempting to instantiate it as if it were an object.

Comment: I know. I need more code to get it to the goal I want to achieve, which is getting the location of the object in the object as a string.

Comment: Maybe I'm just having some troubles getting the idea, but I'm not quite getting what you're asking. If you want to set a named attribute in `attributes`, simply instantiate it as an object with `{...}` instead of `[...]`

Comment: That isn't what I'm trying to achieve. I'm trying to convert code to a unparsed string, basically converting it to the code before it turns into an object.

Eg: obj.attributes[i] (presuming i is an integer) and instead of turning into the object that it should become, it would be obj.attributes[0], or some other integer.

Comment: *"I want to embed into an HTML element as a string"* - Are you saying you want to have something like `<div id="loc1" data-location="obj.attributes[0].attr1.attributes[0].attr1"></div>` and then in your JS read that `data-location` attribute and use it to extract that particular field from `obj`?

Comment: Well, it would be more like <input location = "obj.attributes[0].attr1.attributes[0].attr1" oninput = "parse(this.location)"/> So that it would get the location and alter it based on the value of the location attribute, but you have the right idea.

Comment: Please put those details directly in your question. And please edit your `obj` definition to actually be valid JS.

Comment: I added the details. I just realized my mistake. Thanks for the feedback, the JavaScript should be correct now.

Comment: There are several questions here on SO about turning a "location" into a "string". However, you shouldn't really need to do this. Instead, consider consider representing your "locatIon" as a **function** which, when applied to the object, returns the value you want..

Comment: Could you direct me to the question that is? I'll take down my question as soon as I find the right answer, and I'd love to see that solution.

Comment: What part of the string varies?  So far, I have `'story.s1.choices[${i}].link.lore'`

Comment: https://github.com/deoxxa/dotty

Comment: danh, Other parts that can vary could be like this:
story.s[${i}].choices[${i}].link.choices.[${i}].link.choices[${i}]... etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of representing your "location" as a string, which has to be created, and then untangled, store it as a function which, when applied to the object, returns the desired "location":

```
function pickValue(obj) {
  return obj.s1.choices[0].link.lore;
}
```

Now you can pass this function around, or store it in a variable, and when the time comes, **apply** it by saying

```
myLore = pickValue(story);
```

On a slightly more advanced note, you can create a function which creates a function which gets the lore for the *n*th choice:

```
function makeNthPicker(n) {
  return function(obj) {
    return obj.s1.choices[n].link.lore;
  };
}
```

Now you can do

```
firstPicker = makeNthPicker(0);
console.log(firstPicker(story);
```

Comment: Well... This isn't what I was going for... If I had a more complex sequence, such as story.s1.choices[0].link.choices[3].link.choices[2].link.choices[1].name, your function wouldn't work.

Comment: Also, what if I wanted to edit the lore later? This is what I was going for, and it doesn't look like you can edit the object within the function. This is a good solution but it doesn't fit my needs for editing the object.

Comment: You need to explain your needs in more detail.

Comment: Well persay I had a bigger object with the choices I described in my previous comment. How would I be able to get to it then? Your method has given me some perspective on how to achieve this, though, and I will try modifying it to my purposes.

Comment: The basic question is, why do want to create these strings, and what do you plan to do with them?

Comment: I added that to my question as well, so you know why I want this.

Comment: **Any** reference to the inside of an object, no matter how complicated, can be, and should be, represented as a function, or series of functions, if you build it properly, possibly including the use of functions to build functions as I have shown. The functions can be parameterized with the things that are dynamic, such as the `i` in your example. You are going down a rabbit hole with your idea to represent the inner object as a string.

Comment: Okay, I think your answer is sufficient. As soon as I have created a function that is appropriate for my uses, I will accept your answer. Thanks for helping, torazaburo.